# Resolving paths within HTML from another domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, path

I need to get an HTML from another domain, highlight some words in it and display it in an iframe, keeping the look and behaviour of original page.

So, I pass the page's URL with Ajax script to a PHP file, which retrieves HTML content with CURL, processes it, and returns it to Ajax script. Then I put processed content into an iframe. Now, everything is OK except that paths to all website's resources are relative to another domain's root (beginning with just '/'), so naturally page inside my iframe is rendered without any CSS, JS, images etc. Also, all website's navigation links are naturally dead.

What's the best way to handle this? Especially considering that obtained HTML can also contain paths relative to the document as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<base href="http://www.theotherwebsite.com">
```

Comment: Well this is indeed related to my question. I tried inserting <base> element with href attribute of another domain's URL to processed HTML's head. It almost seems to work. Only, for some reason, within iframe it gets prepended to body instead of head, so if page is within some subdomain, it generates strange results. Some of resources get loaded, others don't.

Comment: Still, an answer should be that, an *answer*. Not a question. In this form it's just a comment. Maybe some rephrasing is enough and maybe Jochen can push it just a bit further to solve your issue.

Comment: This is as good as it gets. Certainly better than to meddle with regex replaces inside obtained HTML's links, which was only think I could think of. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Actually it is good to a certain point. When you add AJAX into the parsed content or if you use SSL you might want to use the regex replace solution...